# Can I connect my AVM FRITZ!DECT 301 Intelligent Radiator to Google Home?

Tags: google-home

For temperature control I have a AVM FRITZ!DECT 301 Intelligent Radiator. Currently, interacting with it with the FRITZ Box system feels burdensome and it would be great if I could switch it ON and OFF in the new Google Home interface of Android 11 that come up when long-pressing the power button.

Is there a way to set this up?